# Anti-Debugging technique in Os-monitor

Tags: ollydbg

Im trying to bypass some trial functionnalities in os-monitor, the point is, after running it through ollydbg, a notification appears to tell that executable segment is encrypted with exe-packing algorithm.

[image]

I ignored that, and continue to execute it, then another notification said that program halted because a debugger is detected.

[image]

Can anyone enlighten me of what type of antidebugging technique is used in this software?

Comment: the first msgbox is from ollydbg warning that the exe is packed the second one is from the application and it may be using almost infinite varieties of antidebugging techniques. look for peter ferries paper on anti debugging techniques  for an overview of antidebugging implementations that could be used in that software

Comment: @blabb which PE decryption tool you recommend me, in order to unpack this code? and how would i know which technique is used to prevent debugging.

Comment: there is no shortcut to deal with unknown your query is too broad to fit here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can anyone enlighten me of what type of antidebugging technique is
>   used in this software?

Yes, that `Protection Error` message is from [ASProtect](http://www.aspack.com/asprotect32.html)'s unpacking stub.

From http://www.aspack.com/asprotect32.html, it features the following antidebugging techniques:

> - compression of the application
> - encryption of the application
> - counteraction to dumping application memory using tools like
>     ProcDump
> - application integrity check
> - counteraction to debuggers
>     and disassemblers
> - counteraction to memory patching
> - API for
>     interaction between application and protection routines
> - creation and
>     verification of registration keys using public keys encryption
>     algorithms
> - keeping of the database and checkup of "stolen" (illegal)
>     registration keys
> - possibility to create evaluation (trial) versions,
>     that limit application functions based on evaluation time and the
>     number of runs left
> - expose nag-screens
> - generating of registration
>     keys, based on the specific computer system.